# is there a way to make template for set of nodes?

Tags: nodes, theming

Is it possible to make a template for set of nodes in Drupal 7
for example page--node--[601-602-603-604].tpl 
and if so what is it?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do like you explain.

What you can do instead is to add a custom template suggestion for the specific nodes in the preprocess_node function to make the nodes use a specific template that can have any name.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to style a page of nodes of a certain content-type or a node of certain type.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
   //some other stuff
    if (isset($variables['node'])) {  
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__type__'. $variables['node']->type;
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page__node__" . $variables['node']->nid;
  }
}
```

Then you would have page--type--machine_name.tpl.php, etc...